# Kendo UI Grid virtual scroll hiding some records

Tags: kendo-ui, scrollbar, kendo-grid

We're using lots and lots of Kendo grids, many of which have virtual scrolling set up with a server-side data source.

Sometimes, one of them will hide records beyond the "reach" of the virtual scrollbar. We can see what's going on by using Developer Tools to make the internal scrollbar visible:

[image: bad virtual scrollbar]

It's hard to put a finger on when this happens exactly - the bug keeps popping up in seemingly random places.

Any ideas how to narrow this down / deal with it?

Comment: You should post a code sample to reproduce.

Comment: I'm going to hold off on adding code for now - I can dig deep into my code on my own at some point, but I was curious if anyone else had encountered similar behavior and could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Telerik (more or less) points out in the [docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/appearance), changes to the rowheight in a grid with virtual scrolling won't work when the grid has `display: none`.

We had an event handler that would hide the grid and fire an async call. On success of the async call, we were changing a value that resulted in a different rowheight (removed bold from one row).

That was enough to throw off the scrolling as pictured.

Answer (score 3):

Try resetting the virtual scroller in the grid onDataBound event.

```
 onDataBound: function(evt) {
        //Repaint the virtual scroll bar to make sure all rows are visible to user 
        var grid = evt.sender.wrapper.data("kendoGrid");
        grid._rowHeight = undefined;
       grid.virtualScrollable.refresh();
    },
```

You need to do this on detail row expand and shrinks as well.

Answer (score 3):

I tried virtualScrollable.refresh(), does not fully shown the hidden content, but using resize(true) works

```
$("#yourGridId").data("kendoGrid").virtualScrollable.refresh(); //does not fully show hidden content

$("#yourGridId").data("kendoGrid").resize(true); //works
```

just need to call this from all the related events (still working on identifying them)